# Передача данных

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Меня интересует вопрос по передачи данных с помощью javascript допустим есть два сайта расположенные на разных хостингах возможно ли с одного сайта отправить переменные на другой и вернуть результат с помощью JS.

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для кроссдоменных запросов используйте формат [JSONP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Если используете jquery запрос будет выглядеть примерно так.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://domain.com/",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        }
 });
```

Comment: Спасибо. Примерно так я это и представлял.